# iPhone UI design to go

Tags: iphone, ui-design

Does anyone know of something that will let me design or at least sketch out iPhone interfaces on the go? I'm at school about 6 hours of the day, and that's when I get the best ideas, and need to actually make a rough draft of my design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't say what level of technology you typically have available to you.

If you have an iPad, I highly recommend [Penultimate](http://www.cocoabox.com/penultimate).  There are other sketch-type apps around, but this one is my favorite.  Simple, and beautiful.  There aren't any interface mockup templates or anything, it's just a freehand sketch app.

If you don't have an iPad, might I suggest going low-tech?  I never go anywhere without pencil and notepad.  My personal weapons of choice are the [Moleskine Large Reporter, Plain](http://www.moleskines.com/klmrl717.html), a [Tul 0.7 Mechanical Pencil](http://www.tul.com/mechanicalpencil.php) (which clips nicely onto the Moleskine's strap closure), and some [iPhone templates](http://www.firstand20.com/images/uploads/iPhone-graph-paper.pdf) (which can be printed out, cut to size, and tucked into the Moleskine).  You could also throw in a [stencil kit](http://www.uistencils.com/products/iphone-stencil-kit), but I usually just freehand it.

Answer (score 0):

Balsamiq Mockups is great for mocking up anything from a Desktop UI to a website to a iPhone app. It has some nice skins and controls for iPhone apps in particular. It also runs on air, which makes it great for cross-platform support and it also means that it can run in the browser (which you have an option to do from their site).

http://balsamiq.com/products/mockups

There is also a site to download more UI components for this software: http://mockupstogo.net/

The only downside is that the software is not free... :-(  However, you can demo the software and I really do think this is worth investing in.

You also mention designing/sketching out your design, which might work nicely since the mockups will look sort-of sketchy, but you have the benefit of going back and editing it later.